# Plotting a few Maclaurin Series in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion, webmathematica

I would like to plot the Taylor polynomials for several functions. Specifically:

```
Exp[Sin[x]]
( x^2 + Exp[ x ] )^( -1 )
```

and

```
Exp[ -4 x^2 + 5 x]
```

I have their Taylor series as:

```
taylorFunction1[x_, n_] := Normal[Series[f1[x], { x, 0, n} ] ]
taylorFunction2[x_, n_] := Normal[Series[f2[x], {x,  0, n} ] ]
taylorFunction3[x_, n_] := Normal[Series[f3[x], {x,  0, n} ] ]
```

I would like to plot the functions of x and their Taylor series of degree `n = 10` and compare each, specifically over the interval [-1/2, 1/2]. However, for some reason, whenever I use the "Plot[]" command, Mathematica just returns an empty graph. I come from a C programming background, but I am rather unfamiliar with Mathematica. Can anyone help me out and let me know what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: It's because (probably -- guessing without `Plot` code) in `Plot`, the symbol `x` is given a numeric value whereas `Series` would fail if `x` is not a symbol.

Comment: Hmm... So do you think changing the variable for x in the function definitions would do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@Normal@Series[{Exp[Sin[x]], (x^2 + Exp[x])^(-1), Exp[-4 x^2 + 5 x]}, {x, 0, 5}],
 {x, -1/2, 1/2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for the response. I see... So is Mathematica actually evaluating the functions, and then plotting every value with x = [-1/2, 1/2]?

Comment: @AlexanderSwanson Yes, the trick is to evaluate `Series` before assigning values to `x`.

Comment: I see. I'm assuming Evaluate@... does that for us. Thanks a lot, Michael.

Comment: @AlexanderSwanson Right, `Plot` evaluates its argument in a [non-standard way](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html), which `Evaluate` overrides.